# Removing element from json array

Tags: javascript, node.js, json

I have a Json file which i am using to store data but i can't remove something from it without it putting "null," where that element was. I've seen people using splice but it doesn't work for me. This is what happens when i use splice

The code i used was delete JsonObj.Times[index] and JsonObj.Times.splice(index, 1)

Input

```
{
    "Times": [
        {
            "TimeStamp": "1588516643",
            "PremiumTime": "1",
            "ID": "473873947895897",
            "GuildID": "27823978489723789"
        },
        {
            "TimeStamp": "1588516643",
            "PremiumTime": "1",
            "ID": "473873947895897",
            "GuildID": "27823978489723789"
        }
    ]
}
```

What It Does

```cs
[
  {
    "TimeStamp": "1588516643",
    "PremiumTime": "1",
    "ID": "473873947895897",
    "GuildID": "27823978489723789"
  }
]
```

What I Want

```cs
{
    "Times": [
        {
            "TimeStamp": "1588516643",
            "PremiumTime": "1",
            "ID": "473873947895897",
            "GuildID": "27823978489723789"
        }
    ]
}
```

When i use delete it does what i want but puts null or undefined in the array.

Comment: We don't have enough data to answer this question. Please show the code you wrote to get the output, and what the input data looked like to start with.

Comment: I updated it with the input and the code i used was delete JsonObj.Times[index] and JsonObj.Times.splice(index, 1)

Comment: edit again and put the actual code snippet. Doing a splice should work. It doesn't make sense that you'd lose the entire "Times" section and keep the sub-object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to use `splice()`, you can do something like this:

```js
const obj = {
    "Times": [
        {
            "TimeStamp": "1588516643",
            "PremiumTime": "1",
            "ID": "473873947895897",
            "GuildID": "27823978489723789"
        },
        {
            "TimeStamp": "1588516643",
            "PremiumTime": "2",
            "ID": "473873947895897",
            "GuildID": "27823978489723789"
        }
    ]
}

const res = obj.Times.splice(0, 1);

console.log(obj);
```

[splice()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice)

Comment: It works but do you know why i get this error?

```SyntaxError: Unexpected end of JSON input
    at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
    at F:\Dis\RadiantBot\Scripts\PremiumHandler.js:48:25
    at FSReqCallback.readFileAfterClose [as oncomplete] (internal/fs/read_file_context.js:63:3)```

Comment: @RadiantMin3 what are you doing with the result afterwards?

Comment: it loops through all entries in the array and checks something in them. Then it removes some of them if the condition is met and saves the file

Comment: I don't know what you're doing in order to save it, but this is another question.

Answer (score 0):

If you know where the indexed values are going to end up, or are trying to target first/last values, you can also use the common array manipulation methods, `.shift()`, or `.pop()`.

Answer (score 0):

If I correctly understand, you want to delete a determination element from Times's array.

Let say you have a variable that contains JSON data. It means that you can not have access to the data that are storing the variable because it is of type string.

```
const jsonData = "{
"Times": [
    {
        "TimeStamp": "1588516643",
        "PremiumTime": "1",
        "ID": "473873947895897",
        "GuildID": "27823978489723789"
    },
    {
        "TimeStamp": "1588516643",
        "PremiumTime": "1",
        "ID": "473873947895897",
        "GuildID": "27823978489723789"
    }
  ]
 }"
```

Source: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse

First of all, you have to parse JSON data using JSON.parse() that will convert the data to a JavaScript value or object described by the string. This will allow you to interact with this data.

```
let parsedData = JSON.parse(jsonData)
```

It will create a new variable with parsed data and it contains an object with an array of objects inside of it.

```
parsedData = {
Times: [
    {
        "TimeStamp": "1588516643",
        "PremiumTime": "1",
        "ID": "473873947895897",
        "GuildID": "27823978489723789"
    },
    {
        "TimeStamp": "1588516643",
        "PremiumTime": "1",
        "ID": "473873947895897",
        "GuildID": "27823978489723789"
    }
  ]
 }
```

Second, we will remove the element by index from Times's array that are declared inside our object parsedData.

```
parsedData.Times.split(index,1)
```

Where :
first parameter "index": The index at which to start changing the array.
second parameter "1": An integer indicating the number of elements in the array to remove from the start.

Source: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice

Hope this can help you!